# Reload date from superview

Tags: ios, objective-c, view, superview

I've got two views, view1 calls : `[self.view addSubview:view2.view];` then views2 calls:       `[self.view removeFromSuperview];` and I want to reload data in view1 when view1 reappear but I can't call a method or update a property of view1 because I can't make an`#import "view1.h"` in view2 (I've made an `#import "view2.h"` in view1).

This is my code :

View1.h :

```
-(void)reloadData;
```

View1.m :

```
#import « View2.h » ; 
View2 *view2 = [[View2 alloc]init]; 
[self.view addSubview:view2.view];
```

View2.h :

```
#import « View1.h »
```

View2.m :

```
// I want to call reloadData to reload Data of view1 before removing view2
[self.view removeFromSuperview];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you reorganize your files properly, you can import view1 in view2 and vice versa. You only need to put the `#import "view1.h"` in view2.h if you need any content right there in the .h file. If you only need this in your implementation, you can happily move `#import "view1.h"` in your view2.m file and thus resolve the circular dependency.

Note that in many cases you can skip importing in the .h file if this is only to create instances / paremeters of a type. For example

```
#import "Another.h"

@interface Onething
@property (strong, nonatomic) Another *an;
@end
```

can be changed to

```
@class Another;

@interface Onething
@property (strong, nonatomic) Another *an;
@end
```

This basically tells the compiler that there is a thing called `Another` but that the details are not important right now. You can then later `#import "Another.h"` in the accompanying .m file and work as before.

Comment: I can't call [self.superview reloadData]; in my view2 but the import is good in the .m of view2. self.superview doesn't work why ? It can't see superview, only self.subclass...

Comment: You could add a property to `view2` that links back to `view1`: `@property (nonatomic, weak) View1 *callingView;` (replace weak by assign if you're not using ARC). You can set this in view1 to self and thus have `self.callingView` available in view2.

Comment: In view2.h declare a `@property (nonatomic, weak) View1 *callingView` (and add `@class View1;` above. When creating your view2 (in View1.m) you now can append `view2.callingView = self`. You now can `#import "View1.h"` in view2.m and do `[self.callingView reloadData]` there.

Comment: I think I've done it but I have an : EXC_BAD_ACCESS. This is my code : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9055216/exit-bad-access